# XMO missing in my GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero

Okay so the start of this Nightmare was that I originally sent LTC to changelly then they sent XMO to my MyMonero wallet, the balance was incorrect (0.00000). So I then used the same keys, same address as the payment was sent to, and I opened a monero GUI v12 wallet and waited 30 hours for it to sync. Finally I log into the wallet and it also says 0.00 which is confusing to me where the money really "went." My transaction does show up on [this](https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmo/blocks) block chain explorer Changelly gave me the Output hash of : 276afd09237d2d48f5d6542bae273f09d8e05d31379e38f62c80ad754050bf28  This Hash doesn't show on any of the other Monero Blockchain explorers. I really would appreciate help with this because its causing me an incredible amount of stress and I want to recover my funds. Thank You

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MyMonero if you were sent XMO instead of XMR. As you stated The hash they gave you does not represent a valid Monero transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot receive XMO to the current MyMonero or Monero applications. XMO is not XMR. For the same reason, you wont find your XMO transaction on any XMR block explorers.